# Custom Adapter in Listview, getting an objects variables

Tags: android

I have a listview with a custom adapter, the adapter contains two `TextViews` and one `ImageButton`. The list contains objects of my class `Firm`. When a user presses the `ImageButton` I want to get some information from the `Firm` object, by using a `get()-method`.

**Some Codesnippets underneath**

**My CustomAdapter**

```
import java.util.Vector;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Firm>
{
 Context context;
 int layoutResourceId;   
 static String datesort; 
 ImageButton call;
 Firm mrb;

 Firm currentMRB;
 Vector<Firm> data;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Vector<Firm> data) 
{
    super(context,layoutResourceId,data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context=context;
    this.data = data;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    MyStringReaderHolder holder;

    if(row==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent,false);

        holder= new MyStringReaderHolder();

        holder.gtumcaTvFirstName =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.gtumcaTvFirstName);
        holder.gtumcaTvLastName =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.gtumcaTvLastName);
        call = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder=(MyStringReaderHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    mrb =data.elementAt(position);
    System.out.println("Position="+position);

    holder.gtumcaTvFirstName.setText(mrb.getCompanyName());
    int price = (int)mrb.getPrice();
    String priceString = Integer.toString(price);
    holder.gtumcaTvLastName.setText(priceString);


    call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            Toast.makeText(context, mrb.getNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

        }
    });

    return row;

}
```

Look at the `getView()` function, this contains a `OnClickListener()` method that I want to run when the user presses one of the items in the `ListView`, the function should raise a `Toast` with the object's `get()` method

But it doesn't work. Does anybody know how I can complete this task? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I've found whats wrong, I forgot that the Button was a `ImageButton` rather than a regular `Button`. But how can I get the objects number? My Toast just generates random numbers from the getNumber() method based on all the objects, more specified I want the number of the object in e.g position 3 in my list.

Comment: I've found what I did wrong. So there is another question in the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by doing it this way:

```
 static class MyStringReaderHolder
 {
    TextView gtumcaTvFirstName,gtumcaTvLastName,gtumcaTvBirthDate;
    ImageView gtumcaIvIcon;
    ImageButton call;
 }
```

And create a new instance of the static class

```
        holder= new MyStringReaderHolder();
        holder.call = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        holder.call.setFocusable(false);
```

Finally I added an `OnClickListener` to the `ImageButton`

```
holder.call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {


        Toast.makeText(context,  "" +  data.elementAt(position).getCompanyName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        }
    });
```

Thanks guys! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
call = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
call.setFocusable(false);   <----- add this line
row.setTag(holder);
```

to get the number use **position** variable

```
Toast.makeText(context, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the item that was click in a ListView use this listener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       // The position is passed here, do as you please
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only work outside the CustomAdapter class. I want to use a ImageButton from the layout of the ListView..